# Which size inner tubes to buy?

Tags: innertube

New to cycling and have no idea what size inner tubes to buy for my particular bike.

Following dimensions on tire:

> N28x1.75*36H
>
> 622*19c

Seems to me this is an unconventional wheel size? Was on Wiggle and most tubes seem to be 700x25c.

Comment: Mandatory reading: https://www.sheldonbrown.com/tyre-sizing.html

Comment: The way thats written is kinda weird. You'd expect the 622 x 19 and 36h to be together. Can you link the bike's spec sheet?

Comment: It wasn't clear whether you were asking what size tubes you need or asking for product recommendations. We don't do product recommendations (they're mostly matters of opinion and often go out of date), so I edited the word "size" into your question in a couple of places.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The 622 x 19 is the rim size. 622 refers to an ISO 622 (700c or 29" in mountain bike parlance) wheel. 19 refers to the rim width in millimeters.

The 28x1.75 is 700c x 45 tire size (or equivalently a 29 x 1.75). So, you need a tube suitable for this size. Tubes are sold by ranges, but it's not hard to find a 700c x 28-47c tube (this is what Schwalbe sells). You can also use tubes marked 29" x (some range containing 1.75). If you go to a bike shop and ask for either a 700c x 45 or 29x 1.75 tube, they should have you sorted out in a few seconds.

The 700c = 29" thing is usually 700c for road/hybrids, 29" for mountain bikes but its the same wheel size. Confusingly, another name for 700c is 28". Why? [Aliens](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/ancient-aliens).

As Criggie points out in the comments, make sure your tube has the right kind of valve. You could take your old tube to a shop and they'll sort you out. Or the bike.

Comment: And, of course, a 27" tire of a given width is larger than a 29" tire of the same width.

Comment: It might as well be aliens, but it seems to be mainly German firms that convert 700C to 28" -- which is about right for 700x45C

Comment: @ChrisH - Still doesn't discount aliens. Germany used the metric system before the invention of the modern bicycle. (I'd guess its really a holdover in some way from the UK, but who knows; Aliens are a much easier explanation)

Comment: @Batman their long use of the metric system leads them to be easily confused when aliens bring in these weird things called inches.

Comment: At that rim size its probably a schrader, but worth mentioning "Get the same kind of valve as the old tube"  cos its easy to go wrong.